# How to achieve this raising text with shadow in AE?

Tags: after-effects, 3d

I've been sent this video (image attached) by a client and I'm trying to recreate it so I can add some extra wording to the animation. The text raises word by word, with the 3d shadow extending up with it. I've managed to get the black outline and 3d shadow by adding Stroke and then Repeater with 55 copies at a 0.3 angle. The words are converted from text to shape. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to extend the letters HIGHER. When I add more copies to the Repeater, it extends the shapes backwards (away from the viewer) instead of pushing the letter towards the viewer.

Hope I'm making sense. Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a text layer to a comp.

Make the text layer 3D.

In the Composition Settings, change the 3D render to Advanced 3D
[image: grab]

Duplicate your text layer

Make the top layer text a bright colour, and the lower text layer black

Set the black text layer Geometry Options to have an Extrusion Depth:
[image]

Adjust the 3D rotation or orientation of both text layers so the text is slightly angled from your view:

[image: grab2]

Precomp both layers, choosing "Move all attributes into new composition".

In your master comp that now only contains a single pre-comped layer, make sure the pre-comp layer is 2D not 3D, otherwise the next step won't work.

Right click on your pre-comp layer and choose Outer Glow from the Layer Styles.  Make the Blend Mode Normal, Spread to 100%, and adjust the Size to taste.  Put a bright background layer behind it.
[image: grab3]

Comment: If anyone has a technique for adding a 2D stroke or outline to a 3D comp without having to pre-comp, I'd love to know